# command to mark a block comment as region

Tags: comment, mark

Is there an existing EMACS command to select a block comment? That is, I have

```
/**
 * A Comment
 */
```

I want to set the mark ahead of the `/**` and set the point after `*/`.

I realize there are several ways it can be done, but I don't want to write code if there already is code.

Comment: Yeah this would be the most useful thing in the world.

Comment: There is `er/mark-comment` in the library [`expand-region.el`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/blob/master/expand-region.el).

Comment: I knew someone had to have done it. Make this an answer so I can checkmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) via `package-install`.
There you find `er/mark-comment` in [`er-basic-expansions.el`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el/blob/master/er-basic-expansions.el).

It is suggested to bind just `er/expand-region` to some suitable key sequence.

If you hit this key sequence region is expanded to the current word at first. The region is expanded further and further if you press repeatedly <kbd>return</kbd>. If you start with point in a comment one of the expansions is the current comment.